# Questions on Multi-stage transistor Op-Amp

Tags: transistors, operational-amplifier, multisim

I would like to know how to understand/analyse the circuit below. And sorry but my level in electronics is not that high and I could only tell that the opposing transistors on the left are meant to cancel any current from the input , yet I don't really understand the B stage which I think the C stage is well related to , and if I wanted to analyse the nodes around the circuit apart from (A,B,C) How can I do it ?

Is it by measuring the current on resistors/nodes?

and note that the output voltage of the circuit in node C is zero this is what it meant to be.I would appreciate any help.

Regards

[image: figure]

[figure http://postimg.org/image/4022rfie9/](http://postimg.org/image/4022rfie9/)

Comment: You dont' seem to even recognize a [differential amplifier "long tailed" pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_amplifier#Long-tailed_pair), so the amount of explanation required on your level far exceed what this forum is for. Read a book, e.g. http://ocw.mit.edu/resources/res-6-010-electronic-feedback-systems-spring-2013/textbook/MITRES_6-010S13_chap08.pdf

Comment: Also http://electro.uv.es/asignaturas/ea2/archivos/AN-A.pdf

Comment: This [youtube video by Alan Wolke (W2AEW)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mejPNuPAHBY) is a nice gentle introduction to the differential pair amplifier, and he points to how it might be used for an op amp input stage. His other "Back-to-basics" videos are also an excellent way to get started improving your understanding of electronics.

Answer (score 4):

It will be hard to explain this circuit if you don't have much background in electronics. Q1 and Q2 are a differential input pair. R7, R8 and Q3 create a constant current. So the constant current flowing through Q3 is split between Q1 and Q2. Whichever of them has a higher input voltage will end up passing most of the current. So, when V+ is higher than V-, most of the current will go through Q2. This means that the voltage at point A will increase.

Now, Q4 is strange. Normally at this point, you would have a voltage amplifier stage (VAS). But Q4 is configured as a voltage follower (this looks like an error). Since it is a voltage follower, the voltage at B will basically be the same as A. Yeah, it will be shifted to a different DC point, but the amplitude will be about the same.

Now we come to Q5 and Q6. This is the output stage. This stage is set up so that it does not increase the voltage (it has no voltage gain) but it can supply more current if the load demands it. It is a class B output stage. It is a voltage follower, too, but Q5 supplies the positive portion of the waveform and Q6 supplies the negative portion. The diodes D1 and D2 are meant to allow Q5 and Q6 to have different voltages as inputs so that, hopefully, the crossover distortion is minimized. You can google crossover distortion.

Hope that helps.

Comment: The only place where currents can easily be measured is where they go through resistors. Use a volt meter to measure the voltage across the resistor, then use Ohm's law to calculate the current. When I say measure the voltage across the resistor, I mean put the positive lead on one side, and the negative lead on the other side. You can also measure the voltage at other nodes. In that case, the easiest thing is to measure voltage to ground. That means put negative lead on ground and positive lead at node you are measuring.

Comment: Based on the polarity of the input, Q4 appears to be intended as an emitter follower, which is strange. Just not a very good OpAmp.

Comment: @gsills, good point about the polarity.