# How can i analyse this multi-stage transistor amplifier?

Tags: transistors, operational-amplifier, analog, circuit-analysis, multisim

i am supposed to measure the node voltages around the circuit and then determine the current flowing in the nodes as well as transistors? Can you please tell me the way of doing it .. appreciate it a lot.

[image: figure]

[figure http://postimg.org/image/4022rfie9/](http://postimg.org/image/4022rfie9/)

Comment: You mean you don't know how to measure voltages and currents in multisim in general? Or in a physical circuit?

Comment: we are only asked to measure the voltages by multisim but on how to find the currents we should apply the equations and find out the currents flowing on nodes/transistors

Comment: Well, mkeith [tried](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/196996/questions-on-multi-stage-transistor-op-amp#comment410600_197000) to  answer it, but I'm not surprised he understood something else from your question.

Comment: Why are you asking this question again?

Answer (score 1):

Start by assuming the transistors draw no appreciable base current. Then you find the voltage at the base of Q3. Use the value of R9 to find the current through the emitter/collector of Q3. Assume the inputs are zero and find the currents through Q1 and Q2. Continue the process through the rest of the circuit.

Comment: thanks a lot , what about the nodes? how to tell their current

Comment: @carlos - Go talk to others in your class. You don't seem to understand voltages and currents yet.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

Please refer to datasheet, however I think the method to solve this circuitry and steps are right. I hope this helps.